# Unable to upload image using Multer or run callback function in in express js using React

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, multer

I am a little new to React and programming, and I am trying to upload an image to an amazon S3 bucket I had set up through a post request to my backend using postman. However, whenever I send in the request, I get an error and I don't know why as even the callback function itself isn't running nor is Multer uploading the file to the necessary location. The code itself was working previously, however, I was unable to properly call the images stored. After trying to fix it, the callback function doesn't even upload nor do I see Multer upload the image to the uploads folder. I am wondering what I had done wrong.

This is the code that showcases the original fetch call as well as the javascript creation of the form data with React.

```
const handleSumbit = async(e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("title", title)
        formData.append("price", price)
        formData.append("images", images)
        formData.append("description", description)
        formData.append("sellerId", sellerId)
        // const product = {title, price, images, description, sellerId}
        console.log(...formData)

        const response = await fetch('/api/products/', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: formData,
        header: {
            "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
        }
        })
        const json = await response.json()
```

and on the same file the setting of the image state to be a file is done as:

```
    const fileSelected = event => {
        const file = event.target.files[0]
            setImages(file)
        }
```

On the backend, using express router the code is as follows:

```
//Product Routes
app.use('/api/products', productRoutes)
```

leading to

```
const express = require('express')
const Product = require('../models/productModel')
const multer = require('multer')
const upload = multer({ dest: 'uploads/' })
const {
    createProduct,
    getProducts,
    getProduct,
    deleteProduct,
    updateProduct,
    getProductsBySellerId,
    getImageByKey
} = require('../controller/productController')


const router = express.Router()

//POST and create new product
router.post('/', upload.single('images'), createProduct)
```

And the create product is:

```js
const createProduct = async(req, res) => {
    console.log("calling create product")
    const file = req.file
    console.log(file)

    const result = await uploadFile(file)
    console.log(result)
    const {title, price, description, tags, stock, ordered, customerId, sellerId} = req.body
    let emptyFeilds = []

    if(!title) {
        emptyFeilds.push('title')
    }
    if(!price) {
        emptyFeilds.push('price')
    }
    // if(!images) {
    //     emptyFeilds.push('images')
    // }
    if(!description) {
        emptyFeilds.push('description')
    }
    if (emptyFeilds.length > 0) {
        return res.status(400).json({error: 'Please fill in all feilds', emptyFeilds})
    }

    //Add product to DB
    try {
        const product = await Product.create({title, images: `/productImages/${result.Key}`, price,  description, tags, stock, ordered, customerId, sellerId})
        res.json(product)
    } catch(error) {
        res.status(400).json({error: error.message})
    }
}
```

The function createProduct is never called with none of the console.log running nor the file being uploaded by multer. Whether through react or postman, both don't work so I don't believe it to be a problem with React itself, nor do I see a resulting error output. Can someone help me find the problem? Let me know if you need more code such as the upload function file that connects to s3.

Comment: Remove the `header` from your request, you don't need it and it's incomplete

Comment: I originally didn't have the header in the request, I added it thinking it would fix it and it didn't. Removing still results in an error.

Comment: What is the response to the request on the client-side? Use your browser's dev-tools _Network_ panel to inspect

Comment: It gives the error net::ERR_FAILED and thus failed to load response data. No error on the server side though.

Comment: Doesn't sound like your Express server is running or accepting requests

Comment: That's what I originally thought but all other HTTP requests are working perfectly fine both through postman and the client-server. It is solely this post request that is not functioning.

Comment: Try removing the trailing `/` in `fetch('/api/products/'`. Also, make sure you remove that `content-type` header. The upload won't work properly with that present